# ~/.bashrc not run when logging in as root

Tags: root, bashrc

When I log in as root:

```
ubuntu login: root                                                                                  
Password:                                                                                               
Last login: Tue Apr  7 17:31:14 CDT 2020 on ttyS0                                                       
Welcome to Ubuntu 19.04 (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-38-generic x86_64)
```

My /root/.bashrc (and therefore /root/.bash_aliases) are not run.  Is this normal?  How can I fix this?

Some more info:

```
# getent passwd| grep root                                     
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

My /root/.profile is normal:

```
# cat /root/.profile                                           
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.                       

if [ "$BASH" ]; then                                                            
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then                                                     
    . ~/.bashrc                                                                 
  fi                                                                            
fi                                                                              

mesg n || true
```

$BASH is set correctly:

```
# echo $BASH                                                   
/bin/bash
```

And /root/.bashrc is also normal.  Here's a snippet:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then                                                 
    . ~/.bash_aliases                                                           
fi
```

If I do ". ~/.bashrc" from the command line, it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, it is. /root/.bash_aliases are run instead, and there is no need to fix it.

Comment: Um, ~ is /root when I log in as root, so ~/.bash_aliases is the same thing as /root/.bash_aliases.  So on my system, when I log in as root, /root/.bash_aliases is not run.

Comment: @lord_nimon please modify your question to include the exact path (without the ~ variable) in order to avoid misunderstandings that probably led to the down-votes.

Comment: I've updated it as requested, but I don't understand how anyone could be confused.  ~ has always been the home directory of whatever your login is.  And if you look at the .bash_xxx scripts in /root, they all use ~ and not /root.

Comment: Do you have either a `/root/.bash_profile` or a `/root/.bash_login` file? If either of those exist, it'll be run instead of `/root/.profile`,

Comment: Yes, I do have a /root/.bash_profile.  That was the problem! Thank you! If you post that as answer, I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exists, bash will run that instead of `~/.profile`. Some software installers will helpfully add their setup steps to (usually) `~/.bash_profile`, so even if you delete it (and merge its contents into `~/.profile`), it might get recreated later.

Ideally, I'd recommend moving all the bash-specific things (i.e. sourcing `~/.bashrc`) into `~/.bash_profile`, have it also source the generic `~/.profile`, leaving just the `mesg` in the generic `~/.profile` (so it'll work if you ever start in a different shell)

So here's what I'd put in `~/.profile`:

```
# cat /root/.profile                                           
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.                       

mesg n || true
```

And `~/.bash_profile` (note that it doesn't have to test `$BASH` 'cause it's already in a bash-specific file):

```
# ~/.bash_profile: executed by bash login shells.

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# If the generic profile exists, source that as well.
if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then                                                     
    . ~/. profile                                                                 
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Hy, 
if you try

```
getent passwd| grep root
```

the return of this command is similar to this ?

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

maybee you have different shell than /bin/bash

you can also take a look of your root profile

```
cat ~/.profile
```

you need to have :

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n || true
```

regards

Comment: I have all that.  Everything looks right.  I've updated the question with this info.

Comment: The distro which I run (OpenMediaVault 6 based on Debian 11) did not have a .profile in the root user's home directory. It's .bashrc was never sourced on login. Now after having created a .profile with the content as you stated it, `~/.bashrc`now gets executed automatically on login, and I get the desired customizations. Thanks!